# When parallel processing in caret, verbose messages do not appear in the console

Tags: r, r-caret, doparallel, verbose, worker-thread

I've worked in R and a question arose.

I've made up an R code using the `train()` function in caret library, and I also set the parallel process by `registDoParallel()` in doParallel.

If I execute without parallel processing, then verbose messages arise in my console. But when I apply parallel process, no verbose messages appears...

Here is my code.

```
xgbt_ml_data1 <-
  train(x = TRAIN_SPRS_PRT$data
        , y = TRAIN_SPRS_PRT$label
        , method = 'xgbTree' 
        , tuneGrid = expand.grid(nrounds = c(10,100,1000), max_depth = c(3,6,12), eta = .01,colsample_bytree = seq(.5,.8,.1), gamma = 0, min_child_weight = c(2:10), subsample = .85)
        , metric = "RMSE"
        , trControl = trainControl(
          method = "cv",
          number = 5,
          verboseIter = TRUE,
          returnData = FALSE,
          returnResamp = "all",                                                        # save losses across all models
          ##  classProbs = TRUE,                                                           # set to TRUE for AUC to be computed
          ##  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
          allowParallel = TRUE)
  )
```

Although I set the `allowParallel = TRUE`, single core works for it.
(I've checked in system monitor)

And verbose messages appear in the console.

After I execute command `registDoParallel(core = 4)` then all 4 cores work
and there are no verbose messages.

Is this normal operation?

Comment: Yes, if you consider how parallelization works, you'll realize that displaying messages created by operations on the workers is not trivial and at the least will reduce performance.

Comment: What is your operating system? Are you using RStudio?

Comment: @Roland, It not, not trivial though. A print operation is not as costly as one would imagine.  It is also very frustrating to run a massive experiment and not have any updates 8 hours later as to how far along the experiment is progressing.